# jQuery Cannot add element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create an element and add to an existing one, but for some reason no element is created, and no error is thrown.
I read the documentation, but it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```js
$("#output").add($("<div></div>").add("Hello"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think `.add()` appends to the dom, it just adds to a jQuery selection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you meant to use `append` instead of `add`?

```js
$("#output").append($("<div></div>").append("Hello"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there's a difference between add and append